# Is there a strong case against making my TyphoonAssembly a singleton? If so, why? If not, is there a recommended way to do so?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I'm getting started with `Typhoon` and finding that it is annoying to keep writing constructors with additional `assembly` arguments. So it is tempting to just make my `TyphoonAssembly` a singleton. But I've yet to see that done in any examples, and I do see examples where constructor or property injection is used to provide an assembly. So maybe there is a case against it - it does seem kind of bad, but how bad, I don't know.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a strong case against making my `TyphoonAssembly` a singleton?
2. Is there a way to do so within the framework, or should I just do it my usual way?

Edit: I'm just starting out, but let's say I have a single (for now) `ApplicationAssembly` that is used as follows:

```
- (NavigationController *)customDefaultNavigationController {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[NavigationController class]
            configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                [definition useInitializer:@selector(init)];
            }];
}

- (id<IRootWireframe>)rootWireframe {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[RootWireframe class]
            configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
                [definition useInitializer:@selector(init)];
            }];
}
```

Nothing even worth mentioning, but the point is that I have at least three or four clients of this assembly in my new application that is still at the "Hello World" level of functionality.

Going forward, if I need to be writing initializers with assembly parameters, I'll do it, but if I can get away with just making my `ApplicationAssembly` a singleton (or scoped in an object that is) then I will.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you mean? ie Assembly without constructor (assume you mean initializer) vs with.

Comment: I am just starting this app and evaluating the library so I have edited but there is very little to the assembly (nothing even that does anything, it just inits everything)

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to see what you meant as it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Answered. . you were asking about the assembly itself right, and not the scope of components that get built by it?

Comment: Correct... I figured out how to make a singleton using the Assembly, but I didn't know how to make the Assembly itself

Comment: @JasperBlues actually I have one follow-up question ... so once I've done the plist integration, and now I am a client trying to make something with the assembly, what is the codez for me to reference the current instance of the assembly?

Comment: @JasperBlues okay, one more question for you: would you recommend moving all "factorylike" objects functionality into the assembly?

Comment: You can inject the assembly itself into wherever its needed, including the initial AppDelegate, or RootViewController: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself  . . for more details, ask a new question if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything will break if you make your assembly a singleton, but it should never be necessary. Your assemblies contain recipes or blueprints to instantiate objects, and at startup, behind the scenes, all of this information goes into a `TyphoonComponentFactory`. The assemblies themselves, at this point, have essentially done their job, and its now the responsibility of the TyphoonComponentFactory to build or emit a scope-cached instance, when asked. . .

. . after startup, we continue to use the assembly interfaces, so that we don't have to resort to 'magic strings', but this just results in Objective-C message forwarding through to TyphoonComponentFactory's `componentForKey` method.

You can bootstrap a Typhoon (or library, etc) in one of the two following ways:

**Using [plist integration](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Plist-Integration)**

This means that you'll have one instance of TyphoonComponentFactory throughout your application.

**[Manually](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Manual-Instantiation)**

For Example:

```
MiddleAgesAssembly *mainAssembly = [[MiddleAgesAssembly new] 
    activateWithCollaboratingAssemblies:@[
      [QuestsAssembly new]
    ]];
```

In this case, its up to you to retain the `TyphoonComponentFactory` for as long as needed, and in the case of an app, it would generally be throughout the lifecycle of the app. For now I recommend retaining it on the app delegate, although once you're comfortable, you'll see that it could be implicitly retained through [proceeding from one object graph to another](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

So, for either approach of bootrapping Typhoon, there's no advantage to the assembly being a singleton. (In fact for plist integration style, this would simply be ignored).